# CSS3 multiple transitions reversed animation

Tags: css, transition

I have a  div I'm trying to animate with CSS.

```
div {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  -moz-transition:
        width: 1s,
        height: 1s 1s;
}

div:hover {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
```

It works as I want when I hover; the width is first animated, followed by the height after a 1 second delay.  But when I hover off the div, I would like it to do the same animations, but in reversed order; height first, then width.  Is there any way to achieve this using only CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add -moz-transition to :hover too:

http://jsfiddle.net/nvn6p/1/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  And makes it cross-browser compatible.

Basically, I just added the same transitions to the `:hover`, however ... and this is **IMPORTANT** ... you need to reverse the `height` and `width` on the initial `transition`

```
div {
  background:red;  
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  -moz-transition-property: height, width;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
  transition-property: height, width;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  transition-property-duration: 1s, 1s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0, 1s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0, 1s;
  transition-property-delay: 0, 1s;
}

div:hover {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  -moz-transition-property: width, height;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  transition-property: width, height;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
  transition-property-duration: 1s, 1s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0, 1s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0, 1s;
  transition-property-delay: 0, 1s;    
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qknMg/1/