# Pop animation in React navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS` for animation transition, the problem is animation for pop must be reverse of pushing but not the animation for push and pop is the same and screen transition is in the same way.

How can I change animation for pop so, transition animation is reverse of poping??

I try using it in stack that contains topbar but not works:

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
  }}
  mode="card"
  headerMode="screen"
>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="HOME"
    component={HomeStack}
    options={{
      ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
    }}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function HomeStack({
    navigation,
    route,
}: {
    navigation: StackNavigationProp<any>;
    route: any;
}) {
    React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerShown: false,
        });
    }, [navigation, route]);
    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            const onBackPress = () => {
                BackHandler.exitApp();
                return true;
            };

            BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", onBackPress);

            return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", onBackPress);
        }, []),
    );
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <CentralTab {...props} />} tabBarPosition="bottom" lazy>
            <Tab.Screen name="GROUPS" component={GroupsScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="FEED" component={FeedStack} />
            <Tab.Screen name="NEW" component={NewStack} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Comment: does this answer still apply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902552/css3-multiple-transitions-reversed-animation ?

Comment: @Luuk No, I'm using react-native.

Comment: How can i use CSS in ReactNative : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949667/how-can-i-use-css-in-reactnative

Comment: By pop animation do you mean when the user go back to the previous screen? The expected behavior is to go Right to Left when navigating to the new screen and Left to Right when going back?

Comment: @RafaelTavares Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to achieve a Right to Left animation on navigation (and Left to Right when going back) is using the `TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS`:

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/stack';

<NavigationContainer>
  <MainStack.Navigator>
    <MainStack.Screen name="ScreenA" component={ScreenA} />
    <MainStack.Screen
      name="ScreenB"
      component={ScreenB}
      options={{ ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS }}
    />
  </MainStack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

You can see it working in [this Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@rafatcb/react-navigation-next-and-back-animations). Works both on iOS and Android.

Comment: This is works for other screens but not work for stack contains tabbar. I updated question.